# Dont move input when append

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this Github: https://github.com/jessepollak/card
so I'm trying to prevent my input move when I append it to form.
I have this:

```
<div class="card-wrapper"></div>
<form id="cardforms"></form>


var number = document.getElementById("#numinp");  
var att = document.createAttribute("name");
att.value = "number";   
number.setAttributeNode(att);
$('#cardforms').append(number);    

          new Card({
            form: document.querySelector('form'),
            container: '.card-wrapper'
        });
```

Actually is working, but is moving my input to the card:
[https://puu.sh/B1Kba/4eeb8c9543.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ydM4.png)

The other inputs are not being affected because I don't use javascript to refer them, but if I do, all the inputs are overlapping one to another in the same position.

Any idea to handle this?

**Is possible to append, and after running the "new Card" code, un-append or something like that?**
or
**It is possible to put input in a form without moving it from its position?**

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't want it moved, you have to clone it, and put the clone in the new place.  The DOM is a tree structure, and each node can only have one single direct parent.

Comment: Clone it? But then I will have 2 inputs? When I write in the "original" input, what will happen? Thanks!

Comment: Elements are unique from each other.  If you clone it, then changing one will not change the other, unless you write some logic to propagate that change.

Comment: Hmm. So what's the point on cloning?

Comment: To create a second element, that you can put wherever you want, without moving the first one.

Comment: But if I clone the element, I need that element gets all the time the value of the original input. If I change something in the original input, needs to be reflected and updated on the clone, is this possible? Thanks!